# ASP.Net WebAPI RC ILogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I just upgraded to the RC of webApi and found that a whole lot of things are no longer as they were.

We were using the `ILogger` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.common.ilogger(v=vs.108).aspx)  interface to log events/exceptions from inside our API. However after upgrading this no longer seems to exist. Does anyone know where this has gone/what this has turned into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With new WebAPI the ILogger interface has been removed and now you should be using **ITraceWriter** instead as described below:

**Monitoring and diagnostics:** You can enable tracing by providing an ITraceWriter implementation and configuring it as a service using the dependency resolver. The ILogger interface has been removed.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) is the official documentation and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/04/12/tracing-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) is an example to start with ITraceWriter

Answer (score 2):

The ILogger interface was replaced with a more general mechanism for tracing. You can see the details on the new tracing [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/04/12/tracing-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout my [nlog webapi trace writer](https://github.com/dbettin/webapi.nlog). It only works with post RC bits, but it is a straightforward change to get it working against the RC drop.